# JSP page : browser only displays the source code

Tags: jsp, browser, view

A new JSP project was created ,after the start of the tomcat, the browser only displays the source code, how can I deal with this situation?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zABdI.png)

I just want to create a java web project. It's my project structure:

Comment: I have to admit I was expecting to say "access it from your server" but you did. The `page` tag seems to be ok. Well, try to restart you server ... can't really say much more here, sorry.

Comment: Thanks,I had started the tomcat,what's the difference between start the tomcat and access it from my server? @ AxelH

Comment: You need to access the file throught your server to receive a parse file. But you did since you use the localhost:8080 path. What did you use to create the file ? What is the encoding ? Can you paste your code here too ? I don't want to rewrite it ;)

Comment: Hey,@AxelH , I have edited my question.Just after I create my java web project , then set the tomcat , the index.jsp in the browser only displays the source code.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure to added bellow maven dependencies (jar files) to your project?

```
<!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- JSP API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Servlet API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

after page tag, maybe works correctly

Comment: may be add some jar files in your project!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of a JSP created by Netbeans for a Web App project. It works fine.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

It looks like in the langage attribute, there is a space before `java`, can't say if this is the reason, can't say if it is needed.

## EDIT

I did test your code, Netbeans tell me that the language attribute isn't valide, remove the space to correct this. It works fine

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks,@AxelH.There is some config problems in my tomcat,the jsp file is not compiled.

Comment: @heather Is it fixed ?

Comment: It should be fixed, I changed it ,and that is wrong,so the tomcat exits some problems.